# OpenGL Shaders Generate Colors

Tags: opengl, shader, gpu, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I have a sprite 10x10 pixels. How can i change colors with shaders-programm in real-time. 
All the blue color on the sprite turned to green.
All the green color on the sprite turned to white.
ETC...

[Example of Sprite 10x10](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/2405/1010sprite.png)

This is example of test-shader with gray-effect:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main()
{
    vec4 normalColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
    float gray = 0.299*normalColor.r + 0.587*normalColor.g + 0.114*normalColor.b;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(gray, gray, gray, normalColor.a);
}
```

So, with this shader we will do sprite gray...

Help me with code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a 3D texture working as a color converter. You basically use the original color value as the texture coordinates in the 3D texture lookup. I've done this before with a 9^3 and a 16^3 texture for *very* simple color conversion. You'll have to carefully evaluate the 3D texture size for your specific case.

This might not be the simplest solution, but at least it is flexible and doesn't involve hard coded checks in the fragment shader.

You might get away with something simpler, but the question has too little information.